# creating fixed number for id in sql programming

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to have 10 numbers for my id column in sql and number only. I want to check the input is only from 0000000000 to 9999999999. I wrote the following codes but I am not sure where goes wrong as it lets A000000000 pass the checking. Please help me! Thanks a lot!

```
create table member (
  member_id char(10) primary key,
  check (member_id not like '%^[0-9]%' and char_length(member_id) = 10)
);

insert into member values ('A000000000')
```

Comment: Should that be [^0-9] ?

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `member_id not like '%^[0-9]%'`
to
`member_id not ~ '^[0-9]{10}'`

for regular expression `~` operator is used instead of `like`

your example `like '%^[0-9]%'` checks for exact match of `^[0-9]` string in any place

Comment: thanks a lot. I think it doesnt recognise not~ so I just change it to ~'[0-9]{10}'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes - why I wrote that? :0

Answer (score -1):

You made

```
member_id not like '%^[0-9]%'
```

this will make it so that anything except an inverted (^) 0-9 is not allowed.
The way to solve it is to goes as follows:

```
check (member_id LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions. The **only** wildcards for LIKE are `%` and `_` in SQL